# How can I host my flutter web with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

i've try to host my flutter in firebase but it doesn't work.

I already follow the steps of the firebase web and the result is this:[image: Result]
1.firebase init hosting
2.firebase deploy --only hosting

The structure of my proyect is:[image: Struture] And i want the page to go to main.dart

Comment: Have you done a `flutter build web` ?

Comment: Yes, after that i do the deploy comand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i have "estilos" y "responsive" in the same place as main.dart.
[image: This is the structure after the change]

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal then write :

```
firebase init hosting
```

then

```
flutter build web
```

then

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

for more details you can read this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-host-your-flutter-web-app-with-firebase-hosting-67d3e4657002)

Comment: Hi, I already try this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is  discussed in this [github thread](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react/issues/55)

> change your `firebase.json` config slightly. You currently have the
> `public` directory set to `build` but if you look in there, the >`index.html`is the file you're seeing with the "Firebase Hosting Complete"
> message. When you build your app, it is actually being put into
> `build/your-app-name` so you'll need to change the line in `firebase.json`
> from:
>
> ```
> "public": "build",
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> "public": "build/your-app-name",
> ```

Also check above github and these similar cases for more alternate solutions:

- [Flutter web app is missing firebase.json and shows "Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete" when deployed to firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059355/flutter-web-app-is-missing-firebase-json-and-shows-welcome-firebase-hosting-set)
- [Flutter web app won't deploy to Firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70979637/flutter-web-app-wont-deploy-to-firebase-hosting)
- [Firebase deploy displays Welcome Screen with no App Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250471/firebase-deploy-displays-welcome-screen-with-no-app-content)